# Call to odyx what id parameter

Tags: testing, automated-tests

Does anybody use odyx and test automation together. While we have setup everything from projects and added testcases we don't find the correct testcaseid for in the call: `tr/auto?tc=TESTCASEID&u=YOURUUID&st=STATUS"`

Does anybody know which one this is?